# Azure devops variables in helm chart

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

So I have a pipeline where I build a docker image and tag it like this.

pipeline.yaml

```
variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'


stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: 'docker'
          repository: 'repo'
          command: 'buildAndPush'
          Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
          tags: |
            $(tag)
```

I later deploy the image to Kubernetes using Helm charts. I have problem using the `$(tag)` variable in helm charts, in a separate file. I am thinking of doing something like this:

deployment.yaml

```
name: app-name
image: docker/image:$(tag)
port: 8080
```

This does not work as it's read literally and I'm getting an error image `docker/image:$(tag) cannot be found`. I have tried using `${tag}` and `${{ variables.tag }}` but the results were the same.
How can I access a variable set in azure pipeline from a helm chart?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables) about how to define variables, you should create a variables.yaml file with as content variables defined in the forms `key: value` or `name: value`.

*<Key: value>* format:

```
variables:
    tag: $(Build.BuildId)
```

or *<name: value>*:

```
variables:
    -  name: tag
       value: $(Build.BuildId)
```

Then, according on how you defined the variables, use it in your deployment.yaml and pipeline.yaml files as:

```
variables['tag'] #for key: value definition like your case
${{ variables.tag }} 
$(tag)
```

Comment: But do I use it ad $(tag) in the pipeline yaml? I am trying to do use the variable in deployment.yaml which is a separate file. I did not specify that in my question, let me fix that.

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply. I have tried your solution but it still failed.  When adding  variables['tag'] to deployment.yaml I get Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Comment: Have you tried to declare the variables as <name: value>: 
  `variables:
    -  name: tag
       value: $(Build.BuildId)`

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply again. I have tried that as well but the result was the same